# Is it that the pebbles are moving due to the rain -of the rain?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Mary Oliver's poem *[wild geese](http://www.rjgeib.com/thoughts/geese/geese.html)*, is it that the pebbles are moving due to the rain

> You do not have to be good.
>   You do not have to walk on your knees
>   For a hundred miles through the desert, repenting.
>   You only have to let the soft animal of your body
>   love what it loves.
>   
>   Tell me about despair, yours, and I will tell you mine.
>   
>   Meanwhile the world goes on.
>   
>   Meanwhile the sun and the clear ***pebbles of the rain***
>   
>   are moving across the landscapes,
>   
>   over the prairies and the deep trees,
>   
>   the mountains and the rivers.
>   
>   Meanwhile the wild geese, high in the clean blue air,
>   
>   are heading home again.
>   
>   Whoever you are, no matter how lonely,
>   
>   the world offers itself to your imagination,
>   
>   calls to you like the wild geese, harsh and exciting —
>   
>   over and over announcing your place
>   
>   in the family of things.

Comment: `1` Please state your question in the question itself, not just in the title. `2` Please cite your source.

Comment: It's [poetry](http://www.rjgeib.com/thoughts/geese/geese.html). Pebbles of the rain = drops of the rain. Or maybe rain clouds, since they are moving.

Comment: Source Mary Oliver's poem wild geese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this poem the literal phrase "pebbles of the rain" refers to the [falling raindrops that look like small stones](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/60/9f/7b/609f7b437f369169461e63308bb96d2a--dew-drops-rain-drops.jpg).

It may also have a *metaphorical* meaning, but that's for you to interpret.